# Prepending an image to the top of another image

Tags: java, java-6, jai

I've been looking for a solution for the last several days.

I've seen an [example of composite images](http://darksleep.com/player/JavaAdvancedImaging/CompositeExample.java.html) with **Java Advanced Imaging**. But that seems to be restricted by the smallest width and height of either image files. So it outputs a file with the height and width of the header file.

*Preferably*, I'd like to have the header not covering any part of the body image. But it's not a requirement. Sometimes the body image's width is smaller than the header and that's fine as the main content of the header file will be in the middle.

Using **JDK 1.6.0_41**, I need to take the first two images:

[image: header_image]

[image: Body image]

And have the result be:

[image: Final result]

Whether it is using Java or Javscript is fine. The entire process is as follows:

I take a canvas object of a map using OpenLayers, then use a POST to send it to a Java Servlet to be processed and stored. Then later retrieved the image if the user desires.

The long blue header needs to be at the top of an image or just above it. The header image will have content from the user that created it, etc. That I **can** do. But manipulating multiple images is not something I am familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you can do this:

```
public BufferedImage prependImage(BufferedImage image1, BufferedImage image2) {
    Dimension d1 = new Dimension(image1.getWidth(null),
            image1.getHeight(null));
    Dimension d2 = new Dimension(image2.getWidth(null),
            image2.getHeight(null));
    Dimension dt = new Dimension(d1.width, d1.height + d2.height);

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(dt.width, dt.height,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    g.drawImage(image1, x, y, d1.width, d1.height, null);
    y += d1.height;
    g.drawImage(image2, x, y, d2.width, d2.height, null);
    g.dispose();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Preliminary tests seem great. I may have to switch to another format instead of Tiffs because it wasn't working until I switched to PNG files. Going to convert the files and try again, but it looks perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Tested it out with the converted files. It works great. Thanks a lot, Gilbert!